# When I try add firebase add firebase sdk

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments
>   [com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0' in build.gradle file of project level.

```
    buildscript { 
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
                //otherS
            }
        }
```